# How to ignore next duplicated row?

Tags: mysql, sql

I need your help!
I have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE `table` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `res` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `value` int(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- Records of table

INSERT INTO `table` VALUES (1, 'gold', 44);
INSERT INTO `table` VALUES (2, 'gold', 44);
INSERT INTO `table` VALUES (3, 'gold', 45);
INSERT INTO `table` VALUES (4, 'gold', 46);
INSERT INTO `table` VALUES (5, 'gold', 44);
INSERT INTO `table` VALUES (6, 'gold', 44);
INSERT INTO `table` VALUES (7, 'gold', 44);
INSERT INTO `table` VALUES (8, 'gold', 47);
```

i need to make SELECT request which will ignored next or previous duplicated rows and i receive data like this:

```
 - gold:44 (ignored 1 record)
 - gold:45 
 - gold:46 
 - gold:44 (ignored 2 records)
 - gold:47
```

there is no object which duplicated record will ignore (first,second,last).
(i tried to use group by value or distinct but this way removes other records with same value)

Comment: Please show what you have tried already...

Comment: I can't see why you want to do this?

Comment: The only way to make this work by using MySQL variables and/or making a lag() or lead() function like in T-SQL to check the next and previous row

Comment: do you need to do this in SQL? it would be considerable more easy and save (see MatBailie's comment to your solution) to do tasks like this in a programming language that is capable of working sequential and can handle loops.

Comment: DISTINCT res, value ??

Comment: can you make changes on the inserts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this with a `gaps and islands` solution.
- Normally that involves `ROW_NUMBER()` which is not present in MySQL
- The solution below mimics `ROW_NUMBER()` with variables and `ORDER BY`

Link to example : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/32e72/12

```
SELECT
    MIN(id)   AS id,
    res,
    value
FROM
(
    SELECT
        IF (@res = res AND @val = value, @row := @row + 1, @row := 1)     AS val_ordinal,
        id              AS id,
        res_ordinal     AS res_ordinal,
        @res := res     AS res,
        @val := value   AS value
    FROM
    (
        SELECT
            IF (@res = res                 , @row := @row + 1, @row := 1)     AS res_ordinal,
            id              AS id,
            @res := res     AS res,
            @val := value   AS value
        FROM
            `table`,
        (
            SELECT @row := 0, @res := '', @val := 0
        )
            AS initialiser
        ORDER BY
            res, id
    )
        AS sequenced_res_id,
    (
        SELECT @row := 0, @res := '', @val := 0
    )
        AS initialiser
    ORDER BY
        res, value, id
)
    AS sequenced_res_val_id
GROUP BY
    res,
    value,
    res_ordinal - val_ordinal
ORDER BY
    MIN(id)
;
```

If I add `res_ordinal`, `val_ordinal` and `res_ordinal - val_ordinal` to your data, it can be seen that you can now differentiate between the two sets of `44`

```
                                                              GROUP

INSERT INTO `table` VALUES ('1', 'gold', '44');   1 - 1 = 0   (Gold, 44, 0)
INSERT INTO `table` VALUES ('2', 'gold', '44');   2 - 2 = 0

INSERT INTO `table` VALUES ('3', 'gold', '45');   3 - 1 = 2   (Gold, 45, 2)

INSERT INTO `table` VALUES ('4', 'gold', '46');   4 - 1 = 3   (Gold, 46, 3)

INSERT INTO `table` VALUES ('5', 'gold', '44');   5 - 3 = 2   (Gold, 44, 2)
INSERT INTO `table` VALUES ('6', 'gold', '44');   6 - 4 = 2
INSERT INTO `table` VALUES ('7', 'gold', '44');   7 - 5 = 2

INSERT INTO `table` VALUES ('8', 'gold', '47');   8 - 1 = 7   (Gold, 47, 7)
```

NOTE: According to your data I could use `id` instead of making my own `res_ordinal`.  doing it this way, however, copes with gaps in the `id` sequence and having multiple different resources.  This means that in the following example the two golds are considered to be duplicates of each other...

```
1   Gold    44     1 - 1 = 0   (Gold, 44, 0)
2   Poop    45     1 - 1 = 0   (Poop, 45, 0)
3   Gold    44     2 - 2 = 0   (Gold, 44, 0)  -- Duplicate
4   Gold    45     3 - 1 = 2   (Gold, 44, 2)
```

Comment: It say MySQL not T-SQL

Comment: @DieVeenman - Updated to use MySQL logic to mimic `ROW_NUMBER()`, thanks for spotting that :)

Answer (score 1):

```
select t1.*
from `table` t1
where not exists ( select 1
                   from `table` t2
                   where t1.id = 1+t2.id 
                   and t1.res = t2.res
                   and t1.value = t2.value
                 );
```

works fine

Comment: Works given the assumption that there are never any gaps in the IDs.  Which in a relational database is a dangerous assumption; there can be gaps due to inserts of other resources, failed inserts, deletes, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use the DISTINCT clause to select unique rows like so:

> SELECT DISTINCT res, value FROM `table`

Comment: Notice that gold:44 is supposed to be returned twice.

Comment: Hmm is just did, I'll try to look for answer

Answer (score -1):

Use `Select DISTINCT res, value FROM table` ... to avoid redundancy

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: "i need to make SELECT request" okay, then I misunderstood him